# Identify and interpret binary file

Tags: image, encryption, binary, tiff

I have an old application that stored images (scanned B&W page) in a large binary file. I have worked out how to single out the individual pages, but I can't decipher the binary for each page. As far as I know, the original pages were TIFF images. The resulting binary is also 1/16th the size, so has obviously been compressed. I'm also not sure of the "endianness" of the files. How would I go about identifying how this file has been stored/compressed or even possibly encrypted? I've included the binary for one of the (smallest) pages (This page should be white with a small line of text in the middle). The original was 58k. Incidentally, all of the pages have the same 14 byte header.

```
01 05 22 28 8E A9 F0 70 BD EF 03 2E EE 0F D8 B8 31 9B B8 03 D0 85 21 81 81 05 74 71 31 25 40 17 34 1E EF 07 A0 8B BD 29 A0 5B D6 C8 B8 B9 0A 31 30 01 26 48 12 B8 30 88 91 70 B0 D0 71 E0 62 63 E2 C2 80 CB 81 2B E2 2E AF F5 82 8B F4 39 AA 98 C5 FD 0B 4F 80 0C F5 37 8E 17 A0 B2 BF 5B 69 09 0E CC 2F 70 B6 44 07 BA 5D C3 E3 F8 55 41 81 EB 68 D6 E2 C7 53 14 1A 5C 74 B8 3C B8 88 F9 C8 A4 97 27 6A E2 69 95 A5 20 B1 EC A3 04 2B 5A E7 4F 93 AD EB 12 27 62 1F 9C 28 7D 60 C4 B4 E9 23 F4 68 8D A1 47 AA 8F 1B B1 3E 6E A4 3E 92 88 7D 24 A5 8F 62 91 6D 35 5A 7C 75 19 97 76 6E 0D A3 B6 86 B2 DC 61 80 18 D2 F6 58 6C 96 98 F5 0F 2A 9F 25 41 DD 9E CF D9 15 E1 FA 3E FC 24 F1 38 98 98 F9 F1 1F 8E C7 C6 DE DD 18 F4 99 6D 85 83 8B 91 1F FF 61 75 DB 69 C4 42 47 C7 7D 4E D7 C9 02 82 5B 0E 22 B8 18 30 96 39 F0 67 51 2C D5 93 1C AA ED 29 CE 16 4C DB 36 BC 69 D3 94 AD 4C C7 40 F0 96 A1 6C 62 A1 D0 8D C5 6C 82 BB 8E 41 F4 65 24 E8 70 B1 B1 56 6C 0B 8C B4 16 FF 8A 5A 45 90 60 83 28 0C 7C BF 50 02 63 93 0E D6 5F 98 F8 78 6A 7E 61 6D 6D CD 6A A9 E1 AC 3E 56 E9 9F BB 4F FF 8D 6E 0C F8 23 4D 32 0B AD 4E BB C2 03 FE 01
```